# Selenium getting text from WebElement Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, web-crawler

Hello I want the get the data printed from my size webelement

This is the site HTML

```
<div class="size-option"><label class="custom-input type-box size-box">
                            <input class="form-control" type="radio" name="sizeChartId" value="163" data-quantity="4">
                            <span class="checker-box">8</span>
                        </label><label class="custom-input type-box size-box">
                            <input class="form-control" type="radio" name="sizeChartId" value="164" data-quantity="5">
                            <span class="checker-box">8.5</span>
                        </label><label class="custom-input type-box size-box">
                            <input class="form-control" type="radio" name="sizeChartId" value="165" data-quantity="3">
                            <span class="checker-box">9</span>
                        </label><label class="custom-input type-box size-box">
                            <input class="form-control" type="radio" name="sizeChartId" value="167" data-quantity="8">
                            <span class="checker-box">10</span>
                        </label><label class="custom-input type-box size-box">
                            <input class="form-control" type="radio" name="sizeChartId" value="168" data-quantity="5">
                            <span class="checker-box">10.5</span>
                        </label><label class="custom-input type-box size-box">
                            <input class="form-control" type="radio" name="sizeChartId" value="169" data-quantity="3">
                            <span class="checker-box">11</span>
                        </label></div>
```

`print(size.text)` gives me

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'

Here is my element
`size=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='product']/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div")`
and

```
for value in size:
    print(value.text)
```

Doesn't work

`print(size[0].text)`

Just give me empty, but I want the span Numbers in a list printed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since "size" is a list of web elements if you wish to print text values of all it's elements, you have to iterate through the list and print each element text, like this:

```
size=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='product']/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div")
for el in size:
    print(el.text)
```

Otherwise, if size intended to be a single element, I have no idea what is the `"//*[@id='product']/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div"` XPath locating  - if so you should use

```
size=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='product']/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div")
```

instead of

```
size=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='product']/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div")
```

Comment: Thanks, you appreciate you taking the time